# R - Removing a specific row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called and df and I want to remove a row for a specific row which contains NA.

Comment: Please add your data using `dput`. If the data is big use `dput(head(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, you should provide a reproducible `R` example. If I understand correctly you can easily use [`subset` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset).

```
# Generating some fake data:
set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame("StudyID" = paste("Study", seq(1:100), sep = "_"),
                      "Column" = sample(c(1:30, NA),100, replace = TRUE))
```

Use `subset` with `!is.na()` if your `NA` is a *Not Available* value

```
newdf <- subset(df, !is.na(Column))
```

If your `NA` is a character:

```
# Numeric to character conversion
df$Column<- as.character(df$Column)

# Replace missing values with "NA"
df$Column[is.na(df$Column)] <- "NA"
```

Thus, just subsetting:

```
newdf <- subset(reviews, Column != "NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using grepl from base R, considering NA as a character.

```
pattern<-"NA"
df <-df[!grepl(pattern, df$Column),]
```

If possible share sample data for better clarity on the data